# The package manager tlgmr appears to be non-functional

Tags: packages, linux, texlive-2018, centos

I am trying to install several packages on my local TeXLive installation, but upon executing, e.g.

```
tlmgr install physics
```

(to download the [physics package](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/physics/physics.pdf)), I am getting:

```
*** WARNING ***: Performing this action will likely destroy the RHEL TeXLive install on your system.
*** WARNING ***: This is almost NEVER what you want to do.
*** WARNING ***: Try using dnf install/update instead.
*** WARNING ***: If performing this action is really what you want to do, pass the "ignore-warning" option.
```

Apparently, this exact problem has appeared twice online ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60415292/r-markdown-problems-to-knit-on-linux) and [here](https://dickimaw-books.com/blog/tex-live-and-fedora/)), but I would like to hear opinions from this stack exchange on how to proceed (I also note, this appears to be the first submission of this problem on this website). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Useful Information**

1. Operating System: Centos8
2. TeXLive Version: pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018) kpathsea version 6.3.0

Comment: The problem is that your installation of TeX is not a pure TeXLive, but is managed by the package manager of your distribution. Ubuntu has exactly the same "problem" (it's not a problem, it's basically a stability-oriented choice). My suggestion is to do a local, portable install of TeXLive. You can look here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu/95373#95373

Comment: as the message says you should use your linux package manager not `tlmgr` if you installed a linux packed texlive rather than getting it direct from TUG

Comment: Greetings to both @Rmano and @David_Carlisle. Thank you a lot for your replies. Indeed, by abandoning the in-build Centos installation and installing a new one, everything appears to be working brilliantly. The new installation has a lot of packages and I can freely install additional ones with `tlmgr`. Thanks!